# Horizontal scroll with dynamic elements

Tags: css

I have squared elements that will appear on the screen extension in a row.

These elements come dynamically then I have 2 as I have 50. Depending on the size of the screen and how many elements that i have i will have a overflow. When this happens I want to display a horizontal scroll.

Follow [here](http://jsfiddle.net/M5X3a/) the fiddle that i tried

The code:

HTML

```
<div class="wrap-poltrona">
    <div class="poltrona"></div>
    <div class="poltrona"></div>
    ...
    <div class="poltrona"></div>
    <div class="poltrona"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap-poltrona{
}
.poltrona{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `inline-block` instead of `float`, add this on the CSS:

```
.wrap-poltrona{
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:auto;
}
.poltrona{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/M5X3a/2/

Answer (score -2):

Another idea is to have viewport and a long enough div to hold all the objects inline.

HTML:

```
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="object"></div>
        <div class="object"></div>
        <div class="object"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.viewport {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.wrap {
    width: 1000000px;
}
.object {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```